# Elastic search nested match_phrase issue

Tags: elasticsearch

We are doing match_phrase query on nested objects, where nested object has a string value only.

We intended to find string phrase occurrences.

Lets suppose,

1) Mapping is as follows.

```
"attr": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "attr": {
                        "type": "multi_field",
                        "fields": {
                            "attr": { "type": "string", "index": "analyzed", "include_in_all": true, "analyzer": "keyword" },
                            "untouched": { "type": "string", "index": "analyzed", "include_in_all": false, "analyzer": "not_analyzed" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

2) Data is like.

Object A:

```
"attr": [
    {
        "attr": "beverage"
    },
    {
        "attr": "apple wine"
    }
]
```

Object B:

```
"attr": [
    {
        "attr": "beverage"
    },
    {
        "attr": "apple"
    },
    {
        "attr": "wine"
    }
]
```

3) Therefore, on query like

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "_all": {
                "query": "apple wine",
                "type": "phrase"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

We are expecting only Object A, but unfortunately Object B is also coming.

Look forward to your suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, separate array values should have large gaps in their offsets to avoid phrase matching. 
There is a default configurable gap between instances of the same field, but the default value for this gap is 0.

You should change it in the field mapping:

```
"attr": { "type": "string", 
"index": "analyzed", 
"include_in_all": true, 
"analyzer": "keyword", 
"position_offset_gap": 100 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to tell the query to search all terms in one nested doc:

```
"query": {
  "nested": {
    "path": "attr",
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "attr": {
          "query": "apple wine",
          "operator": "and"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A good source of information is http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/6/3/fun-with-elasticsearch-s-children-and-nested-documents/